# Displaying BST in txt file

Tags: c++

I have a function which displaying BST tree in console and it works perfectly for small trees:

```
void BST::display(node *ptr, int level)
{
    int i;
    if (ptr != NULL)
    {
        display(ptr->right, level+1);
        cout<<endl;
        if (ptr == root)
            cout<<"Root->:  ";
        else
        {
            for (i = 0;i < level;i++)
                cout<<"       ";
    }
        cout<<ptr->info;
        display(ptr->left, level+1);
    }
}
```

but when tree comes bigger and bigger, BST doesnt display propertly - propably because I have only 80 digits width in console - so I have to display this in txt file -so I little rebuilt my function to something like this - but I dont know why it doesnt work:

```
void BST::display(node *ptr, int level)
{
    int i;
    std::fstream file_bst( "bst.txt", std::ios::out | ios::trunc );
    if (ptr != NULL)
    {

        display(ptr->right, level+1);
        file_bst<<"\n";
        if (ptr == root)
            file_bst<<"Root->:  ";
        else
        {
            for (i = 0;i < level;i++)
                file_bst<<"       ";
    }
        file_bst<<ptr->data;
        display(ptr->left, level+1);
    }
    file_bst.close();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"?

Comment: I have an output in only 2 lines, for example:
Root->:  1116 314    163    1      0

Comment: I don't like how you open the file. Have you considered adding a reference to `std::ostream` as a parameter? that way you can use the same function for `cout` and eliminate all of the open/close overhead.

Comment: [Check the documentation for `ios::trunc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode) and you'll see why it is a poor choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem just by moving:

```
std::fstream file_bst( "bst.txt", std::ios::out);
```

above

```
void BST::display(node *ptr, int level)
```